# Allowing empty strings in Validator.js

Tags: javascript, validation, express-validator, zod, validator.js

I am trying to combine Zod and Validator.js to validate form data. I want to allow empty strings `""` for optional fields. I think this snippet should work but it does NOT and I cannot figure it out:

```
const alpha = (maxChar: number = 1) =>
  z
    .string()
    .toUpperCase()
    .max(maxChar)
    .refine((value) =>
      validator.isAlpha(value.replaceAll(" ", ""), "en-US", { ignore: "" })
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your use of the `.refine` property. This property is checking the condition `validator.isAlpha(value)`, and that is returning false for empty strings. You can enable empty strings with this simple adjustment:

```js
const alpha = (maxChar: number = 1) =>
  z
    .string()
    .toUpperCase()
    .max(maxChar)
    .refine((value) => 
      validator.isAlpha(value) || value.length === 0
    );                      // ^^^^^^ here!
```